# Install numpy with Pyhon 3.7 on Macbook M1

Tags: python, numpy, apple-m1

I'm working on a project that requires Python 3.7. I'm trying to resolve the mismatch between my `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` by running:

```
pip-compile --output-file=requirements.txt setup.py
```

but I get this error

```
compile options: '-DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.7.13/envs/queue-volume-drivers-3.7.13/include -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.7.13/include/python3.7m -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -c'
              extra options: '-faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers'
              clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c
              clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
              clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
              error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.7.13/envs/queue-volume-drivers-3.7.13/include -I/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.7.13/include/python3.7m -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c -o build/temp.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-12.6-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.o.d -faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers" failed with exit status 1
              [end of output]
        
          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        error: legacy-install-failure
        
        × Encountered error while trying to install package.
        ╰─> numpy
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this error too. It happens because `pip-compile` can't/won't use the pre-compiled `numpy` wheel (which is what `pip install` normally does), and instead tries to compile it locally. It appears `numpy` and macOS's built-in BLAS (Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms) library don't like each other (at least for Python 3.7 and 3.8, which I've tested), so compilation fails.

To remediate this `faltivec` problem, we need to link a different BLAS library. OpenBLAS is good for this.

So the solution is:

1. Install OpenBLAS with `brew install openblas`
2. Run `pip-compile` like so: `OPENBLAS=$(brew --prefix openblas) pip-compile --output-file=requirements.txt setup.py`